# Youtube API PHP Deleting a video w/o Zend class

Tags: php, youtube-api

As the title suggests I do want to delete a video via the Youtube API (V2) in PHP but I can't find anything on the youtube API page but Zend, but I do not want to use Zend.

Where do I start looking or does someone has a quick example for me?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the YouTube framework for PHP, even if you use the stand alone version, uses the Zend functions.

You don't have to use the whole Zend framework, as the parts you need for gdata are built into the stand alone framework.

http://framework.zend.com/download/gdata

Comment: I tried to use it and I refuse to use it, what a bunch of garbage... There really isn't a different way to delete a video via the api?

Comment: Sorry, that's just how it is, unfortunately.